# Dynamic Code Evaluation: JNDI Reference Injection/Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection

Tags: jndi, code-injection, fortify

I had run fortify scan for my one of the module and i have received
 Dynamic Code Evaluation: JNDI Reference Injection vulnerability issue
 which shows on below line

> lookup(dataSource)

where the datasource is dynamic. what should i do to prevent this as i
 cannot make the datasource static since it breaks the project functionality

Also I had issue of Dynamic Code Evaluation: Code Injection when i had run the fortify scan. It shows on the places where i had used eval function which is used for valuating the expression entered in the textbox and process the same script.

> var elem=document.getElementById("jse");
>   eval(elem.value);

what we can remove to resolve these vulnerability without effecting its functionality.

Answer (score 3):

1. The standard way to mitigate this kind of thing is to have a list of valid values for the `dataSource` variable and validate against that list before doing the lookup.

   Theoretically something along these lines would work:

   ```
    List<String> lookup = new ArrayList<>();
    lookup.add("datasource1");
    lookup.add("datasource2");
    lookup.add("datasource3");
    ....

    if (lookup.contains(userInputDatasource)) {
        doLookup(userInputDatasource);
    } else {
        throw Exception("Datasource not found;")
    }
   ```
2. JavaScript eval is [not recommended](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#dont-use-eval):

> `eval()` function is evil, never use it. Needing to use eval usually indicates a problem in your design.

That said a similar approach to the above could be used to verify the input only contains valid values